# Javascript - function is not defined using onclick

Tags: javascript, browserify, require, bigchaindb

I am using browserify to so that I can use the require feature in my javascript.  I have a main.js that imports bigchaindb and bip39 using require.

```
const BigchainDB = require('./bigchaindb-driver')
const bip39 = require('./bip39')
```

I am using: `browserify main.js -o bundle.js` to generate the bundle.js file and I am **ONLY** including this in my index.html.

Last, inside of my index.html I using the onclick attribute to call a function createBook() and getting

> createBook function is not defined

, however the function IS defined in my main.js.  (Yes, the name is the same)

Index.html:

Script inclusion: `<script src="scripts/bundle.js"></script>`

onclick: `<button id="sendButton" onclick="createBook()">Send!</button>`

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: When you bundle, all functions are private to to the bundle, unless you expose them.

Comment: How do I go about "exposing" them?

Comment: https://www.ryandaigle.com/a/expose-javascript-api-with-browserify/

Comment: This is confusing to me at the moment.  Not sure what I would substiture for MyLibrary in my case?  Is this createBook?

Comment: I just figured it out.  Thank you :)

Comment: and what was the problem? Sometimes you need to call global functions using the window i.e. 'window.createBook()'

Comment: I was not exporting the JS file and the function inside of it using module.exports.  It wasn't visible globally.